# Pivot rows to columns in Oracle where number of rows-to-columns can only be determined at runtime

Tags: oracle

Using Oracle 18c and given the following table and data:

```
create table food (type varchar2(20), name varchar2(30));
insert into food values ('fruit', 'apple');
insert into food values ('fruit', 'pear');
insert into food values ('fruit', 'orange');
insert into food values ('veggie', 'peas');
insert into food values ('veggie', 'carrots');
insert into food values ('veggie', 'squash');
insert into food values ('veggie', 'corn');
```

I want to pivot the results such that, if I query for `fruit`, I get the columns:

```
apple pear orange
```

but if I query for `veggie`, I get the columns:

```
peas carrots squash corn
```

My goal is to create dynamic SQL or PL/SQL such that, given the `type`, I get certain columns (and the column length can vary as in the two examples above).

How to do this?
That is, need to know how to pivot rows-to-columns where number of columns can be different but finite.

UPDATE - This comes close but the results are in XML format and I just want the `name` to be columns:

```
select * from food
  pivot xml (min(type) for name in ( select name from food where type = 'fruit' ));
```

OUTPUT -

```
<PivotSet>
  <item>
    <column name = "NAME">apple</column>
    <column name = "MIN(TYPE)">fruit</column>
  </item>
  <item>
    <column name = "NAME">orange</column>
    <column name = "MIN(TYPE)">fruit</column>
  </item>
  <item>
    <column name = "NAME">pear</column>
    <column name = "MIN(TYPE)">fruit</column>
  </item>
</PivotSet>
```

Comment: Have you concidered to do the pivoting/transposing in the application?

Comment: Is the input ( 'fruit', 'veggie' ) also a variable? Or can it be a static value? (Eg `f( 'fruit' )` )

Comment: @Lennart yes, but I would prefer SQL or PL/SQL if at all possible.

Comment: @MichaelKutz yes, the application passes ‘fruit’ or ‘veggie ‘ as a variable.